# Can i use destroy charts in React.js using Chart.js?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, data-visualization

I've been trying to find how to destroy chart in React.js but i couldn't find any of way .
Does anyone know how to do it??

Comment: Why do you want to destroy it?

Comment: I'd like to make a menu bar to change chart type . i was building it with vanilla javascript. so in javascript i had to destroy a chart when i want to change chart type. so I think i should use destroy method in react.js to make editable chart type menu bar

Comment: Ok, so the component receive `type` prop? You can call it in the useEffect with deps array of this `type` prop. That is exactly what is the useEffect for. When type changes, you create side effect. (destroy and reinit chart) 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy

Comment: oh i get it !! thanks !!

Comment: np, added as answer, so confirm it 

Comment: https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the component receive `type` prop? You can call it in the useEffect with deps array of this `type` prop. That is exactly what is the useEffect for. When `type` changes, you create side effect. (destroy and reinit chart)

https://chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy